# Meaning of "relative likelihood".

Tags: probability

I am quoting this from DeGroot's "Probability and Statistics".

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables. The joint probability density function(p.d.f.) $f$ defines a surface over the $xy$-plane for which the height
>   $f(x, y)$ at each point $(x, y)$ represents the relative likelihood of that point. For
>   instance, if it is known that $Y = y_0$, then the point $(x, y)$ must lie on the line $y = y_0$ in
>   the $xy$-plane, and the relative likelihood of any point $(x, y_0)$ on this line is $f(x, y_0)$.

I don't know the meaning of "relative likelihood".Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the quote is using the term "likelihood" rather loosely. Likelihood is a separate concept from probability. What the joint density function gives at each point is a....density (hence the name). I don't know why the text said relative likelihood, which is $L_{relative}(a,b)=\frac{L(a)}{L(b)}$, where the likelihood function is evaluated given a set of data with the parameters becomming the variables: i.e., L(a|X) = P(X|a), where X is a set of data or outcomes and a is a parameter of the distribution.

The quote above appears to be talking about the *conditonal probability* of x given $y_{0}$, which is $p_{X|Y}(x|y_{0}) = p_{XY}(y_{0},x)/\int_x p_{XY}(y_{0},x) dx$, in that case the joint density evaluated at $y_{0}$ is acting in a similar manner to the likelihood function in [Bayesian inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Formal_description_of_Bayesian_inference), but the two are rather different concepts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for additional information. Actually, when I asked a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521575/difference-between-probability-and-probability-density), "relative probabilities" was mentioned for p.d.f. I am now confused!!

Comment: I took a look...I wouldn't use the term "relative probability" to describe a joint density, as relative implies you are comparing it **relative** to something else. I would compare probability density to concentration in chemistry...it is the mass (or in this case probability) you accumulate in a given interval of the random variables range. As an example, if you have 1 L of water with 1 g of salt in it, the total mass = 1 g, but depeneding on how well mixed the solution is, you can have local densities approaching pure salt in some parts of the bottle, which is > 1.

Comment: Many many hanks for taking troubles for me.

Comment: No problem. If it helped, you should select this question as answered so others know you don't need additional input.