# A problem on transformation of a random variable.

Tags: probability, random-variables

> $ f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1  & \text{if $0\le x \le 1$ } \\
> 0  & \text{otherwise }\end{cases}$

Find the PDF of Random variable $Y=\dfrac{X}{1+X}$

$F(Y\le y)=F\bigg(\dfrac{X}{1+X}\le y\bigg)=F\bigg(X\le \dfrac{y}{1-y}\bigg)$

$U=F_x\bigg(\dfrac{y}{1-y}\bigg)$

$\dfrac{dU}{dy}=f(y)\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2}\bigg)$

$f(y)=\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2}\bigg)$

Please check if I did any mistake. I am not sure how to figure out domain after transformation. Heres my try.

$0\le x \le 1$

$1\le x+1\le2$

$1\ge \dfrac{1}{x+1}\ge\dfrac{1}{2}$

$x\ge \dfrac{x}{x+1}\ge\dfrac{x}{2}$

$x\ge y\ge\dfrac{x}{2}$

Is this a correct way to approach result?

Comment: Editing question after looking at someone's answer is not allowed on this site

Comment: @James really ? It's $1$ I know. The only mistake was typo. I wrote the whole pdf see man.

Comment: @James Write down whole pdf then match may be.

Comment: Yes you can not keep editing the question like that you asked for the mistake I pointed it out  and you edited it than what is the meaning o my answer if a new person comes and read my answer what he will think he will think you have not done any mistake I am wrong

Comment: @James No james write the whole pdf in your answer FINAL ANSWER.

Comment: so you are asking me too write down the whole answer??

Comment: @James Is it fine now?

Comment: @James I am saying substitute the value of $f(\frac{y}{1-y})$

Comment: As an alternative to the CDF method, you can simply solve $x$ in terms of $y$ and use the transformation formula (If your $Y$ was defined with higher powers of $X$, this would have been more straightforward. For the problem at hand, it doesn't matter)


$$y=\frac{x}{1+x}
\implies x=\frac{y}{1-y}$$

Naturally, $$0<x<1\implies 0<y<1/2$$

So the density of $Y$ is 

\begin{align}
g(y)&=f\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|
\\&=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}\mathbf1_{0<y<1/2}
\end{align}

Comment: @StubbornAtom I just want to ask. When I tried to calculate the domain of $y$. What was wrong in my method? Why it didn't come out to be $0\le y\le\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Damn1o1 Don't just rely on mechanical manipulations. When $x$ is $0$, $y$ is $0$ and when $x=1$, $y=1/2$; and $y$ is continuous throughout. You could draw a [picture](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=region+plot+%7C+x%2F(1+%2B+x)+%7C+x+%3D+0+to+1) to convince yourself.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I got it but I want to know mistake where it didn't go well. Can I say the way I calculated never works all the time ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Are you studying from ISI?

Comment: @StubbornAtom You are very good in statistics man and I am struggling here pretty hard. Which book do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are simple and practical reasons why one writes $F_X(x)$ and *not* $F_x(X)$ or $F_x(x)$ or $F_X(X).$ If one does not know about this, how would one even understand something like $\Pr(X\le x)\text{ ?}$
\begin{align}
\text{For } 0\le y \le \frac 1 2,\text{ we have } & \frac X {1+X} = 1 - \frac 1 {1+X} \le y \\[10pt]
\text{iff } & \frac 1 {1+X} \ge 1 - y \\[10pt]
\text{iff } & 1 + X \le \frac 1 {1-y} \\[10pt]
\text{iff } & X \le \frac 1 {1-y} - 1 = \frac y {1-y}. \\[10pt]
\text{Therefore for } 0 \le y \le \frac 1 2, \quad & \Pr\left( \frac X{1+X} \le y \right) = \Pr\left( X\le \frac y {1-y} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^{y/(1-y)} 1\, dx = \frac y {1-y}. \\[12pt]
\text{Hence } & f_Y(y) = \frac d {dy}\, \frac y {1-y} = \cdots.
\end{align}

Comment: why the downvote on my answer though your answer is also same as mine

Comment: @DeepeshMeena : I don't know. I did not down-vote your answer.

Comment: ok  but I will upvote your answer because it is correct

Comment: I got very confused. Now everything is fine.

Comment: I just want to ask. When I tried to calculate the domain of $y$. What was wrong in my method? Why it didn't come out to be $0\le y\le\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

---

So you are asking for the pdf

$$F(Y\le y)=F(X\le \frac{y}{1-y})$$
so you can write

$$F(Y\le y)=\int_0^{\frac{y}{1-y}} 1 \, dx=\frac{y}{1-y}$$

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$$

$f_Y(y)$ is your PDF

$\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined  thus   $$(1-y)^2\ne 0$$  $$1-y \ne 0$$ $$y \ne 1$$

also, you want $$0\le\frac{y}{1-y}\le 1$$ Solve it to get your domain

Comment: $f\left(\dfrac{y}{1-y}\right)=1$

Comment: Is this domain ?

Comment: yes solve it $y\ne1$ and solve the rest

Comment: Thanks. I did typo there.

Comment: Can you find me the domain? I did nt understand .

Comment: $0\le y \le 1-y$ how do i solve this inequality  ?

Comment: look at the new solution I updated it

Comment: Could help me find out domain ?

Comment: find points where $$f_y(Y)=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$$

is not defined so your domain is R-{the points where the function is not defined }

$\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined  thus   $(1-y)^2=0$  $1-y=0$ $y=1$  thus your domain is $R-{0}$

Comment: was it you who downvoted me for helping you out?

Comment: No I am trying to find out domain .

Comment: Already updated the answer with the domain. Domain are points  where the function is defined

Comment: Your notation and that of the original poster are a confused mess.

Comment: where is the problem He asked can you point out my mistake I pointed him out his  mistake he asked for pdf

Comment: You have $f_y(Y)$ where you plainly need $f_Y(y). \qquad$

Comment: ok It was a mistake by me thanks for correcting

Comment: Now you have $f_y(y)$ where you need $f_Y(y).\qquad$

Comment: I've up-voted this answer. I think it's main weakness is in that it may put the emphasis in the wrong place. One should try to surmise which points the poster is having difficulty with and emphasize those. This is risky, especially since the poster doesn't usually tell you everything they're thinking. My answer does not try to comment on the messy notation and certain confusions in the poster's own approach.

Comment: @DeepeshMeena Really ? You changed your name?