# Random Sequential Adsorption Paper: Probability or Probability Density?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

While going through a paper on Random Sequential Adsorption ("Dynamics of polydisperse irreversible adsorption: a pharmacological example" by Erban et. al, 2007, https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218202507002091), I come across on page 5:

"...the probability (per unit time) of adsorbing the polymer segment of length z $\leq x = x_2 - x_1$ as

$$
\xi(z, w - x_1, x_2 - w)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2(w - x_1)}{z}, &\text{for } w \in [x_1, x_1 + \frac{x}{2}]; \\
1, \quad &\text{for } w \in [x_1 + \frac{z}{2}, x_2 - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{z}{2}]; \\
\frac{2(x_2 - w)}{z}, &\text{for } w \in [x_2 - \frac{z}{2}, x_2]; \\
\end{cases}
$$
and the probability of adsorbing the polymer segment of length $z > x$ as
$$
\xi(z, w - x_1, x_2 - w)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2(w - x_1)}{z}, &\text{for } w \in [x_1, \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}]; \\
\frac{2(x_2 - w)}{z}, &\text{for } w \in [\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, x_2]."
\end{cases}
$$

Now, in these formulas, the length of the domain is $[0, 1]$, the small interval is of length $z$ with midpoint $w$ and the new gap is [$x_1$, $x_2$]. Later on, $\xi(\cdot)$ is referred to as the "probability density function".

My question is: Is $\xi(\cdot)$ a probability density function? If I integrate over the whole domain, I would expect to get a result of $1$ if so. But in fact, I get a result of $x_2 - x_1 + \frac{z}{2}$ for the upper formula and $\frac{(x_2 - x_1)^2}{2z}$ for the bottom formula. Should this not integrate to $1$?

Comment: This "probability density function" must have been a typo (i could only see one occurrence): as you mentioned, $\xi$ is not a probability density function, and the caption of Fig.1 states "The probability $\xi$ as a function of $w$" (no mention of density).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's good to know. My question then would be (following the answer given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521575/difference-between-probability-and-probability-density), if I multiply each of the interval lengths by its associated probability I should get back the probability density? But that doesn't seem to be correct either - I get a result of -2x + z for the integral of the upper "probability density" and x^2/z for the lower one (i.e. again, not 1 as I would expect)

Comment: I think the issue is that you expect the function over the segment to somehow define a probability distribution. If I understood correctly what this represents, it is the probability (over the choice of z, etc.) that something is "adsorbing" (whatever that means). But it does not need to sum to one, as the segment may also *not* be adsorbed at all at that time step. (again, this is based on my hazy understanding of what this process is supposed to model)

Comment: Ok, I'll have a think about it a bit more and leave the question up in case someone with more background knowledge notices it and shines a bit more light on the topic! Thanks for the help