# Likelihood for continuous sample

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a realization of a random sample $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ from continuous distribution. Then why  $L(\theta)=f_\theta(x_1)\ldots f_\theta(x_n)$ holds? $f_\theta(x_i)$ means $P(X_i<x_i)$ which may overlap with another probability for some $k<i$. Does this hold because $X_i$ are independent?

Comment: The case when the sample is from discrete distribution is more intuitive.

Comment: By the way, $f_θ(x_i)$ refers to the **PDF** of $X_{i}$ at $x_{i}$, not the CDF (whereas $P(X_i < x_i)$ is the CDF).

Comment: That makes sense, but the integral would give $0$ for all $x_i$?

Comment: Do you mean that $P(X_i = x_i) = 0$? Yes, this is true – but remember, the PDF at $x_i$ is *not* the probability that $X_i = x_i$ (for continuous random variables). It is the "probability density" at $x_i$. See e.g. [Difference between Probability and Probability Density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521575/difference-between-probability-and-probability-density/521603) for discussions on the difference between a probability and a probability density (or search for other pages about this).

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Too many concepts and one gets confused.. Then what interpretation does the PDF have for a specific value?

Comment: The PDF at a particular point $a$ gives us the "probability density" at $a$, which is roughly the "probability per unit length" at that point. That is, if $f(a)$ is the PDF value of $X$ at $a$, then the probability that $X$ takes a value in some small interval near $a$ is approximately equal to $f(a)$ times the length of the interval ($P(a < X < a + \epsilon) \approx f(a)\epsilon$). So intuitively, the bigger the PDF value at a point $a$, the more likely $X$ is to take values near the point $a$ compared to places where the PDF value is small.

Comment: See also [Intuition for Probability Density Function (PDF)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442807/intuition-for-probability-density-function-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1) and similar pages.