# product distribution of two uniform distribution, what about 3 or more

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Say $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent and identically distributed uniform random variables on the interval $(0,1)$.

What is the product distribution of two of such random variables, e.g.,
$Z_2 = X_1 \cdot X_2$?

What if there are 3; $Z_3 = X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot X_3$?

What if there are $n$ of such uniform variables?
$Z_n = X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot X_n$?

Comment: If you are after the product of $n$ independent standard Uniform random variables, then the pdf of the product, say $f(z)$ will be: $$f(z) =  \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \log ^{n-1}(z)}{(n-1)!}  \qquad \text{ for }  0<z<1  $$ For $n = 1$ to 5, this yields: $$\left\{1,-\log (z),\frac{\log ^2(z)}{2},-\frac{1}{6} \log ^3(z),\frac{\log ^4(z)}{24}\right\}$$

Comment: @wolfies   Thanks,  this is very helpful

Comment: @wolfies -log(z) gives 4.6 for `z=.01` . I should be doing something wrong. Probability cannnot go over 1.

Comment: My questions is answered. I found this. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105455/how-can-a-probability-density-be-greater-than-one-and-integrate-to-one
Thanks!

Comment: @AsadIqbal: The probability *density* **can** go over $1$.

Comment: How do you use the PDF to get a mean?  E.g. If I have 2 uniform random numbers between 0 and 1, what is the mean of their product?

Comment: @Robert Imagine the PDF as a graph. Then, you can integrate the relevant region under the PDF to get the area, and divide by the length of the interval to get the mean.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

We can at least work out the distribution of two IID ${\rm Uniform}(0,1)$ variables $X_1, X_2$:  Let $Z_2 = X_1 X_2$.  Then the CDF is $$\begin{align*} F_{Z_2}(z) &= \Pr[Z_2 \le z] = \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[X_2 \le z/x] f_{X_1}(x) \, dx \\ &= \int_{x=0}^z \, dx + \int_{x=z}^1 \frac{z}{x} \, dx \\ &= z - z \log z. \end{align*}$$  Thus the density of $Z_2$ is $$f_{Z_2}(z) = -\log z, \quad 0 < z \le 1.$$  For a third variable, we would write $$\begin{align*} F_{Z_3}(z) &= \Pr[Z_3 \le z] = \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[X_3 \le z/x] f_{Z_2}(x) \, dx \\ &= -\int_{x=0}^z \log x dx - \int_{x=z}^1 \frac{z}{x} \log x \, dx. \end{align*}$$  Then taking the derivative gives $$f_{Z_3}(z) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \log z \right)^2, \quad 0 < z \le 1.$$  In general, we can conjecture that $$f_{Z_n}(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{(- \log z)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}, & 0 < z \le 1 \\ 0, & {\rm otherwise},\end{cases}$$ which we can prove via induction on $n$.  I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Fantastic!!!     thanks

Comment: For $Z_2$, how do you go from step 2 to step 3? And 3 to 4?

Comment: I don't understand why $\Pr[Z_2 \le z] = \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[X_2 \le z/x] f_{X_1}(x) \, dx$. Can you help? Is this using conditional distribution? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @JKEG: These are just properties of functions of random variables.

Comment: +1 for breaking up the integral in step 1 into sum of 2 integrals. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand where the first summand of the integral comes from? Why is the integral broken into pieces in that step?

Comment: @synack Suppose $z = 1/2$.  Then if $x = 1/4$, $z/x = 2$.  What is $\Pr[X_2 \le 2]$ if $X_2$ is a random variable that can only ever be between $0$ and $1$?  You have two cases for $\Pr[X_2 \le z/x]$, depending on whether $x < z$, or $x \ge z$; that is why the integral gets split up.

Comment: got it. thanks @heropup

Comment: I just want to clarify that $P(Z_2 \leq z = \int_0^1 Pr(X_2 \leq z/x) f_{X_1}(x_1) dx$ is just an application of the law of total probability, right?

Comment: @MSIS In what way is that just a property of random variables? I cannot see how I would transform one into the other.

Comment: @TheOutZ: I'm not 100% on what is your question , but we're computing: $P(X_1X_2 \geq z)$, which is equivalent to $P(X_1 \geq z/X_2)$

Comment: @TheOutZ :Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MSIS Not really, I think what JKEG and me are trying to get at is why the probability can be represented as an integral $\mathbb{P}(Z_2 \leq z) = \int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{P}(X_2 \leq \frac{z}{x}) f_{X_1}(x) \, dx$. If I remember where my confusion came from correctly, I couldn't work out this identity with the transformation theorem ($\int_{\Omega} X \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, d\mathbb{P}_X(x)$) because this change would always affect $X_2$ (because both $X_1$ and $X_2$ vary under the same variable), if I remembered this right.

Answer (score 34):

If $X_1$ is uniform, then $-\log X_1 \sim \textrm{Exp}(1)$. Therefore, 
$$- \log X_1 \dots X_n = -\log X_1 + \dots -\log X_n$$ 
is a sum of independent exponential random variables and has Gamma distribution with parameters $(n,1)$ and density $g(y) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} y^{n-1}e^{-y}$ for $y\geq 0$. Let $f$ be the density of the product $X_1 \dots  X_n$, then the Jacobi's transformation formula yields
$$ f( h^{-1}(y) ) | \partial h^{-1}(y) |  = g(y), $$
with $h(x) = -\log x$ and $h^{-1}(y) = \exp(-y)$. The substitution $y=h(x)$ in the above equation gives
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}(-\log x)^{n-1} \, 1_{ (0,1]}(x).$$

Comment: You got the range slightly wrong. You are supposed to plug $-\log(x)$, not $x$, into $1_{[0,\infty)}$ to obtain $1_{[0,\infty)}(-\log(x))=1_{(0,1]}(x).$ Once you correct this, I will vote up your answer.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: When you say, "if $X_1$ is uniform, then $-\log X_1\sim \text{Exp}(1)$, you mean that $X_1$ is Uniform with range [0,1], right?

Answer (score 14):

An adaptation of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812234) is given here.

---

**PDF of a Function of a Random Variable**

If $P(X\le x)=F(x)$ is the CDF of $X$ and $P(Y\le y)=G(y)$ is the CDF of $Y$ where $Y=f(X)$, then 
$$
F(x)=P(X\le x)=P(Y\le f(x))=G(f(x))\tag1
$$
Taking the derivative of $(1)$, we get
$$
F'(x)=G'(f(x))\,f'(x)\tag2
$$
where $F'$ is the PDF of $X$ and $G'$ is the PDF of $Y$.

---

**PDF of the Product of Independent Uniform Random Variables**

If $[0\le x\le1]$ is the PDF for $X$ and $Y=\log(X)$, then by $(2)$ the PDF of $Y$ is $e^y[y\le0]$. The PDF for the sum of $n$ samples of $Y$ is the $n$-fold convolution of $e^y[y\le0]$ with itself. The Fourier Transform of this $n$-fold convolution is the $n^\text{th}$ power of the Fourier Transform of $e^y[y\le0]$, which is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-2\pi iyt}e^y\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac1{1-2\pi it}\tag3
$$
Thus, the PDF for the sum of $n$ samples of $Y$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_n(y)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi iyt}}{(1-2\pi it)^n}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac{e^y}{2\pi i}\int_{1-i\infty}^{1+i\infty}\frac{e^{-yz}}{z^n}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{4b}\\
&=e^y\frac{(-y)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\,[y\le0]\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: take the inverse Fourier Transform
$\text{(4b)}$: substitute $t=\frac{1-z}{2\pi i}$
$\text{(4c)}$: if $y\gt0$, close the contour on the right half-plane, missing the singularity at $z=0$
$\phantom{\text{(4c):}}$ if $y\le0$, close the contour on the left half-plane, enclosing the singularity at $z=0$

We can get the PDF for the product of $n$ samples of $X$ by applying $(2)$ to $(4)$
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\pi_n(x)=\frac{(-\log(x))^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\,[0\le x\le1]}\tag5
$$
[image]