# Function of product of two uniform random variables

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

If X and Y are uniform(0,1) then what is the distribution of $X^kY^m$ for some integers k and m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
p(X^k Y^m=t)=\int_0^1dx\int_0^1 dy\ \delta(t-x^ky^m)\ ,
$$
and using the Dirac delta to kill the $x$-integral$$
p(X^k Y^m=t)=\int_0^1 dy\ \Theta\left(0\leq (t/y^m)^{1/k}\leq 1\right) \frac{1}{y^m k ( (t/y^m)^{1/k})^{k-1}}\ ,
$$
$$
=\Theta(0\leq t\leq 1)\int_{(1/t)^{-1/m}}^1 \frac{dy}{y^m k ( (t/y^m)^{1/k})^{k-1}}=\boxed{\Theta(0\leq t\leq 1)\frac{t^{1/k}-t^{1/m}}{(k-m)t}}\ .
$$
Note that the result is symmetric upon the exchange $m\to k$ as it should. It is also correctly normalized, $\int_0^1 dt\ p(X^k Y^m=t)=1$ and reduces to $-\log(t)$ for $k=m=1$ as it should (check this answer [product distribution of two uniform distribution, what about 3 or more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659254/product-distribution-of-two-uniform-distribution-what-about-3-or-more)).

Comment: This misses the hypothesis that $(X,Y)$ should be independent and relies on unconventional notations since $P(X^kY^m=t)=0$ for every $t$. To sum up, do not give this to a maths'TA as solution to some work they asked.