# Find the density function of the product of two uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

$X\sim R(0,1)$ and $Y\sim R(0,1)$ (X and Y are uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1])$

I need to find the density function of W when $W=X\cdot Y$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I like to approach such problems by finding the cumulative distribution function for $W$.

Comment: All right. How would you do that? I must be honest to say, that this kind of problem is a little bit difficult for me. In my probability class, it is the hardest problem we solve. So I don't really have a clue how to start it.

Comment: In the $x,y$ plane, the condition $xy\le t$ cuts out a certain region from the unit square.  Its area is the desired cumulative distribution function evaluated at $t$.  So you want a formula for that, and then to differentiate that formula.  Pictures help a lot with this problem

Comment: The joint distribution of $X,Y$ on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is uniform, so Pr$(W \le w)$ is the area of the unit square "bounded" by the curve $xy = w$.

Comment: You should add to your question that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Without that information the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: A google search shows this popular post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659254/product-distribution-of-two-uniform-distribution-what-about-3-or-more.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (preassuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent):

For $w\in(0,1)$ we have:
$$F_{W}(w)=\int\int1_{(-\infty,w]}(xy)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy=\int^w_0\int^{w/y}_0dxdy$$

Work this out and find PDF $f_W(w)$ as derivative of $F_W(w)$.