# Finding PDF of Geometric Mean

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm stuck trying to write a proof for finding the sampling distribution (pdf) of a geometric mean.

> Suppose $x_1 x_2 ... x_n$ are IID $U(0,1)$, find the pdf of: $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Hint:  What is the distribution of $y_i = -\log x_i$?

Comment: I can use the MGF method to show that $-log(x_i)$  ~  exp(1)

Comment: So what is the distribution of $\sum -\log(x_i)$ or $\frac1n\sum -\log(x_i)$ ?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659254/product-distribution-of-two-uniform-distribution-what-about-3-or-more) post here gives the distribution of $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i=Z$(say). Now all you have to do is to perform a single variable transformation to find the distribution of $Z^{1/n}$.

Comment: For the result see here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3392284/198592