# Finding the limit of a product of random variables.

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have following question and I need to know whether I did it correctly.

Let $ X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d. Uniform ~ $(0,1)$. I need to prove that  $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n\right)^{1/n}$
have a limit w.p 1 and find that limit.

This is what I did so far.

Let $Y = \left(X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n\right)^{1/n}$. Then $\log(Y) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(X_i)$.

Using Strong law of large numbers, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log(X_i)$ converges a.s to its mean. (say $\mu$).

To find $\mu$, I took that $E(\log(X_1)) = -1$. (by transformation and taking expectation).

So  $\log(Y) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(X_i)$. converges a.s to $-1$.

Therefore $Y$ converges a.s to $ e^{-1}$.

Is this correct? Are there any efficient ways of doing this proof other than this way?

Thank you.

Comment: We can compute the distribution of $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659254/product-distribution-of-two-uniform-distribution-what-about-3-or-more) and from there the distribution of $\left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^{1/n}$. But your approach is simpler.

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you for your reply. Did you find any mistake in my method ?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you.