# Conditional Expectation of Uniform-Product

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

So say I have $U_1, U_2, \cdots$ be iid $U[0,1]$, and say $X_n = \prod_1^n U_i$, if $N = \inf\{n: X_n <  10^{-6}\}$, I need to find two expectations

1) $E[N]$

2) $E[X_N]$

My initial thought was convert the uniform random variables to exponentials by taking the negative logarithm, i.e. $-\ln(U_i) = W_i$, thus we have $Y_n = -\ln(X_n) = \sum_1^n W_i$ which transforms $N$ to 
$$N = \inf\{n: Y_n >  6 \ln(10) \}$$ 
which kind of screams coupon collector problem. But now the probabilities of the sampling time is not uniform any more so I am not sure on how to actually calculate the expectation.

Any hints/help on finding the first expectation would be greatly appreciated, in addition any hint on even starting the second expectation would also be phenomenal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you were very close to finishing the first question.

Each $W_i = -\ln U_i$ that follows the standard exponential distribution can be viewed as the waiting time between consecutive occurrences of a simple Poisson process with rate of unity.

In other words, the sum $Y_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n W_i$ that follows the Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ is the waiting time for the $n$-th occurrence of the Poisson process with unity rate.

You have a cutoff time length of $t = 6 \ln 10$. Consider a random variable $N_t$ that follows the discrete Poisson distribution with the probability mass function of

$$P(N_t  = k) = e^{-\lambda t} \frac{ (\lambda t)^k }{ k! }~, \quad \text{where}~ \lambda = 1,~t = 6 \ln 10$$

That is, $N_t$ with the parameter $\lambda t$ counts the number of total occurrences up of a time interval of length $t$ of a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$.

Now, $N$ is actually related to the random variable $N_{t}$ in that $N = N_t + 1$

Formally, we have the equivalence between the **events** $\{ Y_n > t\} = \{ N_t < n\}$ for the waiting time of Poisson process and the count. Therefore we have the following equivalence of events:

\begin{alignat}{2}
\{ N = 1 \} &= \{ Y_1 > t \} = \{ N_t < 1 \}  &&= \{ N_t = 0\} \\
\{ N = 2 \} &= \{ Y_1 < t ~~\& ~~ Y_2 > t \} &&= \{ N_t = 1\} \\
\{ N = 3 \} &= \{ Y_2 < t ~~\& ~~ Y_3 > t \} &&= \{ N_t = 2\} \\
&\qquad\qquad \vdots\\
\{ N = k \} &= \{ Y_{k-1} < t ~~\& ~~ Y_k > t \} &&= \{ N_t = k-1 \} \\
&\qquad\qquad \vdots
\end{alignat}

Thus the answer is simply given by one plus the expectation of a discrete Poisson distribution $E[N] = 1+E[N_t] = 1 + \lambda t = 1 + t = 1 + 6 \ln 10 \approx 14.81551$

---

For the second question $E[X_N]$, it is tempting to consider it as $E[ e^{-Y_N} ] $ and do the decomposition conditioning on $N$.

However, that leads to a summation of a region integral (over the region $Y_{N-1} + W_N > t$) that unnecessarily complicates things. One might as well directly do the decomposition on the [distribution of product of uniform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformProductDistribution.html), which derivation stems from the same approach of [your logarithm transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342587/356647).

With the density for unconditional $X_n$ shown in the linked pages, note that we will be working with $X_{k-1}$ so the power and the factorial are of $(k - 2)$. The case of $k = 1$ will automatically work out fine with some implicit understanding of the functional form.

Consider a general threshold $0 < \tau < 1$ (such that $t = -\ln \tau$) and not just for $\tau = 10^{-6}$ here:
\begin{align}
E\bigl[ X_N \bigr] &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} E\bigl[ X_N ~\big|~ N = k \bigr]  \cdot P(N = k) \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} E\bigl[ X_{k-1} \cdot U_k ~\big|~ X_{k-1} > \tau ~~\& ~~ U_k < \frac{ \tau }{ X_{k-1} } \bigr]  \cdot P( N_t = k - 1) \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left\{ \int_{x = \tau }^1\int_{u = 0}^{ \frac{ \tau }x }  x u \cdot \frac1{ (k-2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{0<u<1}\, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}x \right \} \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left\{ \int_{x =\tau }^1 x \cdot \frac1{ (k - 2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \left[ \int_{u = 0}^{ \frac{ \tau }x } u \, \mathrm{d}u \right ] \, \mathrm{d}x \right \} 
\end{align}
In other words, the conditional expectation is in fact the unconditional expectation on the density $f_{X_{k-1}, U_k}$ (which is a direct product between $f_{X_{k-1}}$ and $f_{U_k}$ since they are independent) over the region $\Omega: \{ (x,u)~|~ \tau < x < 1, \, 0 < u < \frac{ \tau }x \}$. The probability $P(N_t = k-1)$ is exactly the mass over region $\Omega$ thus "cancels with the conditioning mass".

(Surely one can arrive directly at the double integral expression and skip the whole "conditioning". It is after all just a decomposition into disjoint events $\{N = k\}$)

The inner integral is trivial and we have
\begin{align}
E\bigl[ X_N \bigr] &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}  \int_{x = \tau}^1 x \cdot \frac1{ (k - 2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \cdot \frac12 \bigl( \frac{\tau}x \bigr)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x   \\
&= \frac{ \tau^2 }2 \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \int_{x = \tau }^1 \frac1x \frac1{ (k - 2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \frac{ \tau^2 }2  \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ (-\ln \tau)^{k-1} }{ (k - 1)! } \\
&= \frac{ \tau^2 }2 e^{ -\ln \tau } \\
&= \frac{ \tau }2 
\end{align}
This nice result is not a coincidence. In fact, it's easy to prove that $X_N$ has a uniform distribution over $[0, \tau]$.

Again, we do the decomposition of all $X_N$ into disjoint $\{ N = k \}$. For $0 < s < \tau$, consider the CDF as the probability:

\begin{align}
\Pr\bigl\{ X_N < \mathbf{\color{magenta}s} \bigr\} &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left\{ \int_{x = \tau }^1\int_{u = 0}^{ \mathbf{\color{magenta}s}/ x } \frac1{ (k-2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{0<u<1}\, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}x \right \} \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left\{ \int_{x =\tau }^1 \frac1{ (k - 2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \left[ \int_{u = 0}^{ \mathbf{ \color{magenta}s}/x } 1 \, \mathrm{d}u \right ] \, \mathrm{d}x \right \} \\
&= \mathbf{\color{magenta}s} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \int_{x =\tau }^1  \frac1{ (k - 2)! }(-\log x)^{k-2} \cdot \frac1x\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \mathbf{\color{magenta}s} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ (-\ln \tau)^{k-1} }{ (k-1)! } \\
&= \mathbf{\color{magenta}s} \cdot e^{ -\ln \tau } \\
&= \frac{ \mathbf{\color{magenta}s} }{ \tau } \qquad \text{with an implicity}~~\mathbb{1}_{0 < \mathbf{\color{magenta}s} < \tau}
\end{align}
That is, the CDF $F_{X_N}(s) = s / \tau$ is linear and the density is constant over $[0, \tau]$, the uniform distribution as we know it.

Comment: Wow, that was an amazing answer, that clarified alot of my doubts!!!