# Random Area and Perimeter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, expected-value

Lt A and L denote the area and perimeter of a rectangle with length $X$ and height $Y$, such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Find the density function of $A$ and $L$.

Will it just be $$f(x,y) = 2xy(x+y)$$

The above is just my guess and likely wrong, because when I use it to calculate $\mathbb{E}(A)$ and $\mathbb{E}(L)$ , I get the wrong values, so what will be the distribution function?

Comment: area is a product of two uniform random variable. see answers of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659254/59379). perimeter is twice the sum of two uniform random variable. Its PDF is a triangular shaped function.

Comment: You do not need to find the joint density (which is what your $f$ looks like), and this is pretty hard to do.

Comment: Ok, I think I interpreted the question wrong