# How to find $f_{Z|X}(Z|X)$ when a stick is broken 3 parts.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

[image]

[image]

[image]

My work:

[image]

I kind of know how to compute $E(Z)$ and $Var(Z)$ but still don't understand why $f_{Z|X}(Z|X)=1/X$ if $0<Z<X<1.$

Can anyone explain to me specifically how to come up with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Did you understand back in $Example.10.26$ why  $f_{X|Y}(x) = \frac1y$? It's exactly the same here in $Exercise.10.41$. BTW, please [do not use images for the critical part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question, especially here your question is very specific and most of the info in the images is redundant (or can be easily typed).

Comment: In case you're wondering, the marginals of this process is the [product of uniform distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformProductDistribution.html). One can also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659254). In particular, here your $X$ is for $n = 2$ and $Z$ is for $n = 3$.

Comment: Small error: The $E(Z/X=x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{z}{x}dz= \frac{1}{2} x$

Comment: Another observation is $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ when evaluated with $f(x) = -ln(x) $ amounts to the same value as shown in example problem.  So it is doubly correct.