# Can PDF be larger than CDF for continuous RV?

Tags: probability

Let $f$ be the PDF of a continuous RV $X$, and define $F$ to be its CDF: $F(x)=\int _{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$. Can $F(x)$ be strictly less than $f(x)$? This clearly cannot happen in the discrete case ($\mathbb{P}(X\le x) \ge \mathbb{P}(X=x)$). However, in the continuous case, viewing $f(x)$ as the probability of $X$ falling within the infinitesimal interval $(x,x+dx)$ is it possible that the $f(x) > F(x)$?

If $CDF \ge PDF$ in the continuous case, I don't know how to verify it from the definition.

Comment: If only at certain places you may have $f(x)>F(x)$ but as $F(x)$ tends to one as $x$ goes to $+\infty$ you obviously can't have it for all $x$

Comment: Is the set of $x$ for which $f>F$ of measure 0?

Comment: @cap  No, it can even be the entire support.

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105455/how-can-a-probability-density-be-greater-than-one-and-integrate-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   The probability *density* can easily have greater magnitude than the cumulative probability *mass*.   They are measures of different dimensions.

For one thing, a *cumulative distribution function* cannot be greater than $1$ at any point, while a *probability density function* has no such restriction.

As an example: a uniform continuous distribution with the support of $(0;\tfrac 12)$ has a probability density of $2$ everywhere *within its support*.  (Outside the support, however...)