# Given that a variable's probability density function is $p(t)=kf(t)$, how to find $k$?

Tags: calculus, probability

The variable t is defined in the domain $t>0$. At first, I thought $k$ could be calculated by normalizing $p(t)$ to $1$. So $$k = \frac{1}{F(\infty) - F(0)}$$ where $F(t)$ is the primitive function of $f(t)$.

However, I encountered a problem with this type of function, (I applied specific values to give a concrete example):

\begin{equation}
p(t) = k(1+\sin(20t))e^{\frac{-t}{1.5}}
\end{equation}

when using the method above, I found $$F(\infty) - F(0) \approx 1.55$$ But, when plotted, $f(t)$ looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjurK.png)

So for some $t\to 0$, where $f(t)$ peaks, the probability $p(t)$ will be larger than $1$ because $1/k$ is smaller than $f(t)$ there. In this case, how do I find $k$? What constraints should I put in my calculation to make sure that $p(t)$ is always smaller than $1$.

Comment: Only the cumulative distribution function has to be smaller than one. The probability density function may be strictly larger than one. See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105455/how-can-a-probability-density-be-greater-than-one-and-integrate-to-one. (Of course, it may only be strictly larger than one on a sufficiently small interval.)

Answer (score 1):

It's the *integral* of density over its domain that needs to be $1,$ not the density itself, which in some cases can exceed $1$ at some points. For example in a uniform density defined over $[0,1/10]$ the density will be $10$ between $0$ and $1/10.$